# Vue bind multiple v-models to elements in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a v-for loop that creates sections, all of which have a switch component that is set to ON. It is set to on because it is part of this group. The idea is that when one gets switched to OFF it will make an API call to set the new state and be removed from the group.

The trouble that I'm having is that right now I'm binding the switch with v-model and a computed property and when the sections get built they are connected to the SAME property. So if one gets switched to OFF, they all do. I am not sure how to separate these so that when one is clicked it only affects that one. I will also need data associated with the switch that is clicked to make the API call. PS, a click method on the switch element DOES NOT WORK.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" v-for="person in people"> 
     <switcher size="lg" color="green" open-name="ON" close-name="OFF" v-model="toggle"></switcher> 
</div>
```

VUE

```
computed: {
    people() { return this.$store.getters.peopleMonitoring },
    toggle: {
        get() {
          return true;
        },
        set() {
            let dto = {
              reportToken: this.report.reportToken,
              version: this.report.version
            }
            this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_MONITORING', dto).then(response => {
            }, error => {
              console.log("Failed.")
            });
          } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `toggle` to an array:

```
computed: {
    people() { return this.$store.getters.peopleMonitoring },
    toggle: {
        get() {
          return Array(this.people.length).fill(true);
        },
        set() {
            let dto = {
              reportToken: this.report.reportToken,
              version: this.report.version
            }
            this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_MONITORING', dto).then(response => {
            }, error => {
              console.log("Failed.")
            });
          } 
        }
    }
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" v-for="(person, index) in people"> 
  <switcher size="lg" color="green" open-name="ON" close-name="OFF" v-model="toggle[index]"></switcher> 
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I needed but for some reason the switches won't even click now...

Comment: "Won't even click"? What do you mean with this?

Comment: And I updated my answer, I missed `length` in `toggle.get()`

Comment: Ya, I corrected that. The switch toggles don't do anything when you click on them. The set function doesn't run.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the [index] in the v-model. If I take that out, all of the switches move to the off position and the set function runs when clicked.